# How to set a fallback (assets/i18n/en.json) when url is not available (ngx-translate/http-loader)

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I'm using Angular4 (with Ionic Framework) with the @ngx-translate module.

I have in my app.module.ts:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'https://www.example.com/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

How can i fallback to use a local url (e.g. ./assets/i18n/en.json) if www.example.com is down or even worse the internet connection doesn't work at that moment?

I was thinking about this 'solution':

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  if (www.example.com = online) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'https://www.example.com/i18n/', '.json');
  }
  else {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
  }
}
```

Ofcourse my 'solution' doesn't work.... :(
Does anyone has a good suggestion or a working solution how to solve this?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a more current version, the way I solved this in Angular 8 was to create a fallback version of the TranslateLoader. That catches an error/times out if the server fails to responds and instead returns the local files.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class TranslateFallbackHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {

  private static readonly  WAIT_FOR_SERVER = 2000;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
              public prefix: string, 
              public suffix: String,
              public fallbackPrefix: string = "/assets/i18n/",
              public fallbackSuffix: string = ".json") {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {
      return this.http.get(`${this.prefix}${lang}${this.suffix}`)
           .pipe(timeout(TranslateFallbackHttpLoader.WAIT_FOR_WEBTRANSLATEIT), 
                 catchError(error => { 

        console.log("Translation: Failed to get translations from " + this.prefix, error);
        console.log("Translation: Falling back to local files " + this.fallbackPrefix);

        return this.http.get(`${this.fallbackPrefix}${lang}${this.fallbackSuffix}`)}))
  }
}

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): TranslateLoader {
  return new TranslateFallbackHttpLoader(httpClient, environment.i18n.API_URL, '');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since translate is using httpclient i would go with [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses).

```
@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request)
  .do(event => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      this.logger.logDebug(event);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => { 
   //Check for url and 404 and load what you want
  });
  }
}
```